# Ubuntu + Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: broadcom, gpu-driver, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I have a question about Raspberry pi 2 and Ubuntu.

I have seen in YouTube videos Ubuntu runs videos very slow because of NO video driver support in Ubuntu (including other versions / Lubuntu, Linaro , Snappy Ubuntu , Etc) it only has software acceleration NO hardware acceleration.

So I saw Broadcom has released video drivers of Raspberry pi 2 which is VIDEO CORE IV.

My question is : How to install or use those drivers on Ubuntu ? and get Hardware acceleration to YouTube and other apps ?

Also look [this page](http://www.element14.com/community/thread/31944/l/broadcom-releasing-videocore-iv-gpu-documentation?displayFullThread=true&forceNoRedirect=true) too.

Comment: Ubuntu does have some video driver support (otherwise it wouldn't work :), but: 1) youtube using Adobe flash does not support acceleration properly, especially in firefox (you can try HTML5 though) - 2) ubuntu snappy has be released for the Pi for developers, so may not have all features - 3) hardware that needs to run lubuntu etc doesn't always support acceleration anyway

Comment: With the Pi as well, open source drivers have been available [since 2012](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/open-source-arm-userspace/), and also that release was on [Feb 2014](http://www.broadcom.com/blog/chip-design/android-for-all-broadcom-gives-developers-keys-to-the-videocore-kingdom/). However, support may only be available on mainstream versions (Raspbian, openelec etc)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to keep your hands away from the Ubuntu for RPi2. You have issues with video drivers, network drivers (even with dongles that are known to work like charm on the Raspbian), you don't even have basic tools to build stuff (whoever thought it is funny not to include `build-essential` with the shipped image is a brain-damaged person...). I can keep writing but you get the point I hope.